# Can I return Future[Option[Foo]] in spray?

Tags: scala, rest, spray

My attempt so far ran into `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to scala.Option`. In fact I even can not think how the appropriate response may look like. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show the code for which you are getting the `BoxedUnit` exception? It seems like you are nothing returning where you should return the option value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here could be two options: either it's a bug in your program or you didn't provide spray any way to marshall your `Foo` type, cause `Future` and `Option` are handled by default. E.g this route can be handled by standard spray marshallers without any problems:

```
val route = {
  (get & path("test")) {
    complete {
      Future(Option("Hello Spray!"))
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you make a GET request on /test you'll get a correct response.

If you have a specific type, then you need to provide you own marshaller of type `ToResponseMarshallable` to sray through implicit context. I think the most common and easiest way would be to make a Json response, for this you need a spray-json (or some other supported json lib) and just provide a converter to json, like:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Boy(name: String, age: String)
object Boy {
  implicit val boyJson = jsonFormat2(Boy.apply)
}
```

Now the only thing left to do is place a json marshaller into the scope:

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._ // import json marshaller

val route = {
  (get & path("test") {
    complete {  
      Future(Option(Boy("Name", 0)))
    }
  }
}
```

Now you'll get a json response. IF you need some other kind of response, make a custom marshaller for a Boy type.

Comment: @4lex1v Copying and pasting your example results in this type mismatch: `expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actual: Future[Option[TestRoute.this.Boy]]`. TestRoute is the trait this `route` exists in. Have the requirements changed since 2014 for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In short - Yes, but you need to make compiler happy.

Spray lets you return `Future` or plain response as long as it can be marshalled back to a response. You need to make sure that you either have implicit conversions in the scope that do the marshalling for you or transform your `Foo` object explicitly.

Here is how response transformation is performed: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-httpx/response-transformation/.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still getting issues returning a future in the complete block, make sure to have an execution context such as `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` in scope! IDE tends to not understand this is the problem and can send you down a long rabbit hole.